# Can Bearer token validate Message Extension request from MS Teams?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, bearer-token

I created a message extension for an App within Microsoft Teams that when clicked sends the message from Teams to my web service.

(one of these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/define-action-command)

I don't need to authenticate the user, but I want to authenticate that the incoming request came from Microsoft instead of someone maliciously sending me data.

The Authentication method described by [Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/search-extensions#authentication); authenticates the user individually on the system. Which I don't want as the user might not have an account.

There is a Bearer token in the header of the action's incoming request to my web service. Can I somehow utilize this to validate it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't validate the Bearer token sent from MS Teams to your MS Teams App.

The right way to do it is use the "client credentials grant" between your MS Teams app and your web service. The grant is described here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4

Your MS Teams App will be the client. Each request your client sends to your web service will contain a token issued by either your web service or an external identity provider your web service trusts. This token will be validated by your web service to ensure the request is genuine.

This grant is suitable for service-to-service communication you described.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The MS Teams "App" is really just a configuration json file with provided actions and endpoints to call on user submission.

Comment: @adamjames you said you created a messaging extension? That extension surely has a handler?

Comment: The extension points to the URL of my web service. Upon invoking it, Teams sends a set of parameters to the endpoint defined. I don't have any control over the sending from the Teams "app". There is the Auth flow described in the second link where I provide a URL login webview that is shown to the user in Teams, but the user may not have an account in my web service, and they should still be able to send the message. So I simply want to authenticate that the message came from Teams and not a third party.

Comment: @AdamJames so you use the predefined set of parameters.In that case,you could instead use `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync` in `TeamsActivityHandler` (see #51 @ https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) to obtain an access token from your web service or external IDP using `IdentityModel` ([here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/)) and send the request with added `Authorization` header to your web service manually using `HttpClient`, all that while you configure your web service to only allow requests which have the valid Bearer token in the request header.

Comment: @AdamJames sorry, I have just seen the tag `node.js`. There is a nodejs sample of #51 too, you basically extend the `TeamsActivityHandler` class and use the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction` function, where you obtain the access token for your web service and send a request using whatever http library you prefer, with the access token included. It doesn't change the concept.